# How to wait until jquery animation is finished using the onbeforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, animation, onbeforeunload

It looks like a basic problem, but I simply can not solve this. I am using an animation to smooth the navigation between pages. The `window.onbeforeunload` event looks good to fire the animation, but jquery do the animation on a new thread. Is there any way to wait until the animation is finished? I tried using the `delay()` and `setTimeout()` jquery functions but they obviously not stopped the function. When I add a loop at the end to wait, the window is not refreshing so the animation not even shown.

My code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud7e2/3/)):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    $('#loader-sheet').fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: I think `window.onbeforeunload` expects you to return something, like a string that it can display to the user.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to notify them, just do the animation before the browser navigates from the current page to the other one. Bind event to link clicks would be nice, but when you redirected by a script I need an event before navigation.

Comment: I don't think you are able to do that. Unless you control the navigation between the pages yourself (not via a `href="..."`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent the page from changing - you can only present some text as confirmation (e.g. "You have an unsaved draft, are you sure you would like to leave?").

This is by design - imagine if every annoying ad popup was allowed to prevent you from exiting the page by entering a 200-second animation.

However, you might still be able to do something, depending on exactly *why* the page is changing.  For instance, if they are clicking a link on your page (not using back/forward buttons), then you could override the `click` handler for each of those links, like:

```
$('a[href]').on('click', function () {
    if (/* link would change page */) {
        performPageTransition(this.getAttribute('href'));
        return false;
    }
});

function performPageTransition(newUrl) {
    $('#loaderSheet').fadeIn(500, function () {
        // Animation complete - move to new URL
        window.location = newUrl;
    });
}
```

So instead of following the link instantly, you intercept the click event, and then move the page manually yourself later.

However, I would also consider whether it's possible to load the new page content via AJAX.

Comment: The 200 ms limit in the animation was helpful.

Comment: What 200ms limit?  I said something about "200 seconds" (a bit over three minutes) as an illustration of why what you were asking is not allowed - otherwise popups could have an incredibly long "exit animation" that basically made them impossible to close.

Comment: What I was actually suggesting was that instead of allowing the page-change click to happen, to intercept the click event, perform an animation, and then *simulate* the click action (page-change) after the animation is done.

Comment: However, it might be that a 200ms animation might still manage to execute in the brief time before the page re-loads.  That is probably also a workable solution, if all you care about are the visuals.

Comment: Actually it's possible to make the browser crash and hang on a webpage using an infinite loop in the window.unload event

Comment: @Tofandel - If you have a proof-of-concept of that, please submit a bug report to Chromium/Firefox/etc. so it can be fixed. Also, even it were doing relayouts/redraws during that period (which I sincerely hope it is not), I would not recommend it as a sane solution to the original question. :p

Comment: @cloudfeet Yep, that's only plainly anoying to the user, I was just pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

From MDN:

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog.

`onBeforeUnload` is used to prompt a user, not to perform actions (like ajax, animations, or otherwise)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

There's no API to accomplish what you are looking to do. If a user is leaving, the only thing the browser will let you do is prompt them and ask them if they are sure they want to leave. You cannot prevent  them  (or delay them while still maintaining control of the UI, or anything that uses a JavaScript API) from navigating away from your page.

Comment: Thanks! But is there any other event to fire before the navigation? Can I do something with e.preventDefault(); //do the anim then do the navigation manually?

Comment: Ok it looks like a security issue.

Comment: It is indeed a security issue - but if the page change is due to clicking on a link, or something like that, then you can intercept the click instead.